# How to handle errors for values declared outside of funcs in Go source file

Tags: go, init

I have this:

```
var wd, _ = os.Getwd()
var advanceAgreementTemplateBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadFile(path.Join(wd, "/docs/templates/advance-agreement.template"))
var advanceAgreementTemplate = string(advanceAgreementTemplateBytes)
var t, _ = template.New("advance-agreement").Parse(string(advanceAgreementTemplate))

func sendAdvanceEmail(user *common.User, amount *apd.Decimal, fee *apd.Decimal, created time.Time) { 

   // use variables `t`, `advanceAgreementTemplate`  etc here
 }
```

I want to be able to handle the errors in the cached variables instead of using _ instead of err. Is the only way to do this is to use `func init()`?

Comment: Maybe a struct holding those values can be used as what you call a cache? You then setup that struct (and handle your errors) in dedicated function (like main). I would recommend against using global variables and init method if not absolutely required.

Comment: Package template provide Must wrappers you can use and provide your own for the rest too.

Comment: Yeah it's too bad that these calls do not have Must variants :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to error-check these, use `func init` or just initialize them in `main`.

Not all calls have `Must` variants, and such variants don't make sense for all calls. Don't forget that *the Go way* is to do proper error checking. Having `Must` wrappers for all possible failing calls would encourage a bad programming style, where instead of handling and propagating errors, every error would crash by default.

It's very easy to write your own `Must` wrappers if all you need is to crash the program on error.

The benefit of writing your own `Must` wrapper is that you could provide a much better error message - another thing Go encourages. `ioutil.ReadFile` will just say *"open /docs/templates/advance-agreement.template: No such file or directory"*.

Comment: yeah, is there any way around that that you can think of? Why aren't `Must` variants provided for these calls? sad

Comment: @cholosrus because the error cases aren't static. Things like `regexp.MustCompile` make sense because if you're passing a constant value as the regular expression, there's no situation where it "might or might not" work - if it works once, it always works, no matter where you run it. OS and filesystem operations can't say the same; you can take the same binary and run it on different machines, as different users, etc. and sometimes it might fail and others not. `Must` is a convenience for cases where you expect something to *never* fail.